# Create a multivariable equation

Tags: polynomials

I have a function that depends on two parameters: $f(x,y)$. But the only information I have is how $f$ varies as I change either $x$ or $y$, but not both at the same time.
Example:
$$f(x,0)=2x^2+4x+2\tag{0<x<10}$$
$$f(0,y)=y^2+2y+1\tag{0<y<10}$$

If I want to create a single multivariable equation,$f(x.y)$, how can I obtain such equation starting with above information only. Is it a matter of add them up?

Comment: This won't work because it neglects cross terms. Consider $f(x,y) = xy$. $f(x,0) = 0$, and also $f(0,y) = 0$. Yet $f(x,y) \neq 0$. The problem is that this function is non-linear. So the immediate answer to your question is that there is not enough information to extract a single polynomial in two variables.

Answer (score 1):

According to those conditions $f(0,0) = 2$ and $f(0,0) = 1$ (if the function is continuous at the origin) which is a contradiction.

Comment: Ok, ignore the last numbers on those equations (2 and 1), so the equations are: $$f(x,0)=2x^2+4x\tag{0<x<10}$$
$$f(0,y)=y^2+2y\tag{0<y<10}$$ How can I find the single multivariable equation describing the system?

Comment: In that case you could just add them.